# Scala: Cannot change object attribute of var: Assignment to val

Tags: scala

I am confused as to what the issue is here. I have an function:

```
def myFunc(activity:Activity):updatedActivity = {
    //var updatedActivity:Activity = activity <- This doesnt work either
    var updatedActivity:Activity = activity.copy()

    val params =  Params (
      "Attribute"
    )

    updatedActivity.parameters = params
    updatedActivity
}
```

This will not work, because reassigning an attribute `updatedActivity.parameters = params` throws a reassignment of val error, even though updatedActivity is a var. How can I update the activity parameter I passed in and return it?

Comment: `updatedActivity` may be a `var`, but if it's a case class then the attribute `parameters` is definitely a `val`, this is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

updatedActivity may be a var but class Activity has a field called parameters which is a val.
So it must be assigned during construction.

if its a case class, try this:

```
def myFunc(activity:Activity):updatedActivity = {   
    val params =  Params (
      "Attribute"
    )

    activity.copy(parameters = params)
}
```

If it is not a case class, it has to be passed as a regular parameter to the constructor, i.e.

```
new Activity(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `Activity` is a `case class`.  Even though `updatedActivity` is a `var`, the underlying value (case class) is immutable, meaning that you can reassign `updatedActivity`, but cannot change the current value in place.  Instead, you can just return:

```
updatedActvity.copy(parameters = params)
```